# Запятая между деепричастным оборотом и усилительной частицей «и»

Tags: деепричастный-оборот, частица, и

Когда усилительная частица «и» стоит перед деепричастным оборотом, то он не обособляется. А когда «и» стоит после оборота?

Например: ***Смотря на твои поступки и не скажешь, что ты ему враг.***

Comment: *Когда усилительная частица «и» стоит перед деепричастным оборотом, то он не обособляется.* - что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Одиночное деепричастие или деепричастный оборот не обособляется, если перед деепричастным оборотом стоит усилительная частица и: Можно прожить и не хвастая умом (М. Г.); Можете уйти и не дожидаясь ответа; Он оставался скромным и победив сильного противника

Comment: Понял. Извините. Но что касается самого вопроса, то переносить эту формулировку на ваш случай как-то странно.

Comment: теперь извините вы: почему странно?

Comment: Ну потому что формулировки не имеют расширительного толкования. Там же ясно сказано, что усилительная частица стоит **перед** оборотом. А не перед сказуемым. Был бы союз - еще можно было говорить о каком-то равноправии членов, им соединяемых, но тут-то частица - она к деепричастному обороту явно не относится.

Answer (score 1):

***Смотря на твои поступки и не скажешь, что ты ему враг.***

1) И — **усилительная частица**, которая относится к сказуемому.

2) Розенталь рассматривает вариант с усилительной частицей,  отнесенной к деепричастному обороту: если перед деепричастным оборотом стоит усилительная частица и: ***Можно прожить и не хвАстая умом*** (М. Г.); Можете уйти и не дожидаясь ответа; Он оставался скромным и победив сильного противника; http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=113#pp113

Очевидно, что при наличии усилительной частицы ***И*** **пауза отсутствует, логическое ударение ставится только на деепричастный оборот, но не ставится на сказуемое**.

3) Аналогичная ситуация и в том случае, если усилительная частица относится к сказуемому: ***Смотря на твои поступки и не скАжешь, что ты ему враг.***

Здесь ударение падает только на сказуемое, но не падает на оборот. **Соответственно, нет паузы и запятой.**

Comment: А это где-нибудь зафиксировано?

Comment: У Розенталя не зафиксировано, у Лопатина и темы такой нет.  В Грамоте вряд ли найдешь. Остается продолжить поиски или решить задачу самостоятельно. Интонационно варианты совпадают.

Comment: Да чего её решать-то. Не написано - действуй по общему правилу. Да одно и смотрится дико без запятой, вам не кажется?

Comment: Дико смотрится с запятой  при явном отсутствии паузы (мне так кажется). И правила (общего, для усилительных частиц) тоже НЕТ.  В таких случаях используется метод аналогии. Но вот что важно: существующее правило надо понять, объяснить, а потом уже применить к другому случаю. Вот это и называется решением задачи. Впрочем, если вы найдете готовое (другое) решение в авторитетном источнике, я готова изменить свое мнение.

Comment: Я называю "дико смотрится" ситуацию, когда деепричастный оборот не обособляется на основании непонятно каких соображений.

Comment: А Вы Розенталю об этом скажите. Почему это он не ставит запятую в предложении: "Можно прожить и не хвАстая умом". У него-то какие соображения, почему при наличии усилительной частицы деепричастие не обособляется? Вам эти соображения понятны, не кажутся дикими? Может быть, и нам расскажите почему?

Comment: Сказал.Велел вам передать, чтобы вы на него напраслину не наводили. ))))  Он не ставит запятую на основании изложенного им мотива. А в вашем случае мотивов он не нашел. нашел бы - написал.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100700/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------).